# Changing image with dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change an image depending on what option is selected in a drop down menu. I am very new to javascript, so I am sure that it is a small problem that I'm not noticing. My attempt at implementing it is below:

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">             
    function setPicture() {
        var img = document.getElementById("coffeedropdown");
        var value = coffeedropdown.options[coffeedropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        alert(selectedValue);
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<select id="coffeedropdown" onchange="setPicture();">
    <option value="../Images/pimms.jpg">Select a Drink</option>
    <option value="../Images/caffe.jpg">Caffe</option>
    <option value="../Images/caffelatte.jpg">Caffe Latte</option>
    <option value="../Images/cappuccino.jpg">Cappuccino</option>
    <option value="../Images/marocchino.jpg">Caffee Marrocchino</option>
    <option value="../Images/americano.jpg">Caffe Americano</option>
    <option value="../Images/shakerato.jpg">Caffe Shakerato</option>
    <option value="../Images/corretto.jpg">Caffe Corretto</option>
</select>
```

If anyone could help me out with this, I would really appreciate it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `coffeedropdown` variable declared or initialized anywhere, so after initializing `img` variable with your dropdown you need `img` to be used further, as your coffedropdown will be now `img`.

```
var img = document.getElementById("coffeedropdown");
var value = coffeedropdown.options[coffeedropdown.selectedIndex].value;
```

should be

```
var img = document.getElementById("coffeedropdown");
var value = img.options[img.selectedIndex].value;
            ^^^         ^^^ //img here not coffeedropdown
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WCf8P/8/)

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it, in addition to changing selectedValue to value. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function setPicture() {
    var img = document.getElementById("coffeedropdown");
    var value = img.options[coffeedropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(value);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WCf8P/6/)

Comment: Ah, that's a typo. Thanks for catching that. It still does not work. My JS is in the head, does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest Method:)

```
<select id="coffeedropdown" onchange="setPicture(this);">
            <option value="../Images/pimms.jpg">Select a Drink</option>
            <option value="../Images/caffe.jpg">Caffe</option>
            <option value="../Images/caffelatte.jpg">Caffe Latte</option>
            <option value="../Images/cappuccino.jpg">Cappuccino</option>
            <option value="../Images/marocchino.jpg">Caffee Marrocchino</option>
            <option value="../Images/americano.jpg">Caffe Americano</option>
            <option value="../Images/shakerato.jpg">Caffe Shakerato</option>
            <option value="../Images/corretto.jpg">Caffe Corretto</option>
        </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function setPicture(select) {
            selectedvalue=select.value;
            alert(selectedvalue);
        }
    </script>
```